# azure arm template deploying azure key vault extension to a VM

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am attempting to deploy the key vault extension to a VM using an azure Arm template.  Based on this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/key-vault-windows.

I get this error when attempting to provision the extension
Template deployment returned the following errors:
08:57:27 - 8:57:26 AM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions 'dcsvm1/test' failed with message '{
08:57:27 -   "status": "Failed",
08:57:27 -   "error": {
08:57:27 -     "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
08:57:27 -     "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
08:57:27 -     "details": [
08:57:27 -       {
08:57:27 -         "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
08:57:27 -         "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'test'. Error message: "Failed to parse the configuration settings with: 'not an array'"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionwindowstroubleshoot "
08:57:27 -       }
08:57:27 -     ]

```
>     here is the arm template json
>     type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
>           "name": "dcsvm1/test",
>           "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
>           "location": "[parameters('location')]",
>           "dependsOn": [
>             "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines', parameters('virtualmachinename'))]"
>           ],
>           "properties": {
>             "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault",
>             "type": "KeyVaultForWindows",
>             "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
>             "settings": {
>               "secretsManagementSettings": {
>                 "pollingIntervalIns": "3600",
>                 "certificateStoreName": "MY",
>                 "linkOnRenewal": "false",
>                 "certificateStoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
>                 //"requireInitialSync": "true",
>                 //"observedCertificates": "https://testkvdsc.vault.azure.net:443/certificates/wildcard/9817edfba5124579b75649f51902ef99",
>                 "observedCertificates": "https://testkvdsc.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/wildcard"
>               }         
>             }
>           }
>         },
```

I have been able get add the extension after the VM is created using powershell but much rather have it installed via the arm template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to install Azure key vault extension on Azure VM via arm template, the template should be like as below. Please update `observedCertificates`as array and `linkOnRenewal` as boolean.

```
"resources": [ {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMName'), '/KeyVaultForWindows')]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault",
                "type": "KeyVaultForWindows",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "secretsManagementSettings": {
                        "pollingIntervalInS": "3600",
                        "certificateStoreName": "MY",
                        "linkOnRenewal": false,
                        "certificateStoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
                        "observedCertificates": ["",""]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Regarding the details of how to install the extension, please refer to the following steps. Meanwhile, you can refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/key-vault-windows)

1. Enable MSI for the VM
2. The Key Vault Access Policy must be set with secrets `get` and `list` permission for VM/VMSS managed identity to retrieve a secret's portion of certificate.
3. Install the extension

My template is as below

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaultName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "VMName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "tenantId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[subscription().tenantId]"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        }
    },
    "resources": [{
            "name": "[parameters('VMName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned",
            },
        }, {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "nestedTemplate1",
            "resourceGroup": "<key vault resource group>",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('VMName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [{
                            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/add')]",

                            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
                            "properties": {
                                "accessPolicies": [{
                                        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                                        "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('VMName')), '2020-06-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                                        "permissions": {
                                            "keys": ["all"],
                                            "secrets": ["all"],
                                            "certificates": ["all"],
                                            "storage": ["all"]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMName'), '/KeyVaultForWindows')]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "nestedTemplate1"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault",
                "type": "KeyVaultForWindows",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "secretsManagementSettings": {
                        "pollingIntervalInS": "3600",
                        "certificateStoreName": "MY",
                        "linkOnRenewal": false,
                        "certificateStoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
                        "observedCertificates": [""]
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’d guess that your error is with observedCertificates which, [according to this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/key-vault-windows#property-values) document, should be an array of strings rather than a single string. Try surrounding the string with square brackets.